# How to enable right-click with Electron BrowserWindow and BrowserView?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, electron, contextmenu

I have a `BrowserView` inside a `BrowserWindow` (I need both indeed):

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, BrowserView } = require('electron');

app.on('ready', () => {
    browserWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 500, frame: false });
    bv = new BrowserView({ webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: false }});
    bv.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 30, width: 800, height: 470});
    bv.webContents.loadURL('https://old.reddit.com');
    browserWindow.setBrowserView(bv);
});
```

Doing a right-click on web pages doesn't do anything. **How to enable right-click to have "Back", "Forward", "Reload", "Copy", "Paste", etc. as usual with Chrome?**

[image]

Comment: I recommend [electron-context-menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-context-menu)

Comment: @kemotoe Can you post an answer with `electron-context-menu`? It would be interesting to have both solutions for future reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Electron has some sample menus up on their docs located at https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu

```
// Importing this adds a right-click menu with 'Inspect Element' option
const remote = require('remote')
const Menu = remote.require('menu')
const MenuItem = remote.require('menu-item')

let rightClickPosition = null

const menu = new Menu()
const menuItem = new MenuItem({
  label: 'Inspect Element',
  click: () => {
    remote.getCurrentWindow().inspectElement(rightClickPosition.x, rightClickPosition.y)
  }
})
menu.append(menuItem)

window.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  rightClickPosition = {x: e.x, y: e.y}
  menu.popup(remote.getCurrentWindow())
}, false)
```

Following this template you could set up custom roles like `Back`, `Forward`, `Reload`, etc. using custom javascript like this:

```
Back
```

```
const backMenuItem = new MenuItem({
  label: 'Back',
  click: () => {
    window.history.back();
  }
})
menu.append(backMenuItem)
```

```
Forward
```

```
const forwardMenuItem = new MenuItem({
  label: 'Forward',
  click: () => {
    window.history.forward();
  }
})
menu.append(forwardMenuItem)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution!